# Am using two date pickers to obtain the year range.how can i set the second year to be greater than the first year entered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's the code am using for each of the two years to be selected.

please am confused.i want help.i want to add a year picker to every input field that will be added not only one.and i want to make the entered second to be greater than the one entered first.thanks

```
$('body').on('focus', ".datepicker", function() {
  $(this).datepicker({
    minViewMode: 2,
    format: 'yyyy'
  });
}
});
```

```html
<div class="panel-body">
  <form method="post" action="">
    <div class="input-group control-groups after-add-more-inputs">
      <input class="from form-control" name="study[]" placeholder="FROM:(ENTER YEAR)" style="width:22%;" type="text">
      <input class="to form-control" name="study[]" placeholder="TO:(ENTER YEAR)" style="width: 20%;" type="text">
    </div>

    <div class="copy-field hide">
      <div class="control-groups input-group" style="margin-top:10px">
        <input class="from form-control" name="study[]" placeholder="FROM:(ENTER YEAR)" style="width:22%;" type="text">
        <input class="to form-control" name="study[]" placeholder="TO:(ENTER YEAR)" style="width: 20%;" type="text">
        <div class="remove">
          <a href="#"> Remove</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="add-more-inputs">
    <a href="">Add</a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Sir am requesting for dynamically input fields

Comment: can any one out their  help me please